# How do I clear the terminal screen in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, terminal, ghci

How can I clear a terminal screen after my user has selected an option from my application's menu?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what user interface system you are using in your Haskell program? Do you mean that you are simply reading and writing text to stdin/stdout? If so, those have no implicit concept of "screen".

If you intend your program to work assuming that there is a terminal attached to stdin/stdout, then you should be coding your program to use some terminal control package, such as indicated @ZackS' answer.

Comment: Please choose the correct answer. People have to go through all answers!

Answer (score 225):

**:!**   run the shell command 
**:! cls**          under windows
**:! clear**        under linux and OS X

Comment: is there any cheatsheet for ghci?

Comment: @Peter my best guess is it's because they don't think it's a haskell solution (rightfully so; it only works in GHCi), it doesn't work for them (shell-dependent) or they just consider ZachS' answer a better one. `:! cls` is plenty sufficient for my use case but doesn't work for the asker's case as the asker isn't using GHCi.

Answer (score 63):

This is what you may be looking for:

**[ansi-terminal:](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ansi-terminal/0.5.0/doc/html/System-Console-ANSI.html)** Simple ANSI terminal support, with Windows compatibility

You can find it in Hackage and install using `cabal install ansi-terminal`. It specifically has functions for clearing the screen, displaying colors, moving the cursor, etc.

Using it to clear the screen is easy: (this is with GHCI)

`import System.Console.ANSI

clearScreen`

Comment: This is the correct answer.
Try to look for the package in your system’s package manager though, as cabal generally doesn’t work with that and doesn’t offer an uninstall command.

Answer (score 21):

Just press Ctrl+L (works on Windows)

Comment: Works on macOS too

Comment: Works on ubuntu + zsh as well.

Answer (score 18):

On a terminal that understands ANSI escape sequences (I believe every term in Unix/Linux systems) you can do it simply with:

```
clear = putStr "\ESC[2J"
```

The `2` clears the entire screen. You can use `0` or `1` respectively if you want to clear from the cursor to end of screen or from cursor to the beginning of the screen.

However I don't think this works in the Windows shell.

Answer (score 10):

On Windows, use **Ctrl + L** for Haskell command prompt terminal. And, for GUI use **Ctrl + S**.

Comment: Works on Linux as well.

Answer (score 9):

On Unix systems you can do `System.system "clear"` which just invokes the command-line utility clear. For a solution that does not depend on external tools, you'd need a library that abstracts over different terminal-types like for example [ansi-terminal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ansi-terminal).

Comment: @Pradeep: Yes, and I answered in haskell.

Comment: @Pradeep: No need to shout. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Internet )

Answer (score 7):

A quick way on Windows would be to

```
import System.Process

clear :: IO ()
clear = system "cls"
```

Comment: This was the cleanest solution for me, and for Linux systems use `system "clear`.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux (Ubuntu at least), that's the code I use for clearing the terminal:

```
import qualified System.Process as SP

clearScreen :: IO ()
clearScreen = do
  _ <- SP.system "reset"
  return ()
```