# Output ascii animation from Haskell?

Tags: animation, haskell, ascii-art

I’m trying to get a very quick and dirty animated display of some data produced using Haskell.   The simplest thing to try seems to be ASCII art — in other words, something along the lines of:

```
type Frame = [[Char]]     -- each frame is given as an array of characters

type Animation = [Frame]

display :: Animation -> IO ()
display = ??
```

How can I best do this?

The part I can’t figure out at all is how to ensure a minimal pause between frames; the rest is straightforward using `putStrLn` together with `clearScreen` from the [ansi-terminal](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ansi-terminal/0.5.0/doc/html/System-Console-ANSI.html) package, found via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472391/how-do-i-clear-the-terminal-screen-in-haskell/2472538#2472538).

Comment: if you clear the screen it's going the be flickering. there is an ascii fractal zoomer for haskell, check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's a rough sketch of what I'd do:

```
import Graphics.UI.SDL.Time (getTicks)
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

type Frame = [[Char]]
type Animation = [Frame]

displayFrame :: Frame -> IO ()
displayFrame = mapM_ putStrLn

timeAction :: IO () -> IO Integer
timeAction act = do t <- getTicks
                    act
                    t' <- getTicks
                    return (fromIntegral $ t' - t)

addDelay :: Integer -> IO () -> IO ()
addDelay hz act = do dt <- timeAction act
                     let delay = calcDelay dt hz
                     threadDelay $ fromInteger delay

calcDelay dt hz = max (frame_usec - dt_usec) 0
  where frame_usec = 1000000 `div` hz
        dt_usec = dt * 1000

runFrames :: Integer -> Animation -> IO ()
runFrames hz frs = mapM_ (addDelay hz . displayFrame) frs
```

Obviously I'm using SDL here purely for `getTicks`, because it's what I've used before. Feel free to replace it with any other function to get the current time.

The first argument to `runFrames` is--as the name suggests--the frame rate in hertz, i.e., frames per second. The `runFrames` function first converts each frame into an action that draws it, then gives each to the `addDelay` function, which checks the time before and after running the action, then sleeps until the frame time has passed.

My own code would look a bit different than this, because I'd generally have a more complicated loop that would do other stuff, e.g., polling SDL for events, doing background processing, passing data to the next iteration, &c. But the basic idea is the same.

Obviously the nice thing about this approach is that, while still being fairly simple, you get a consistent frame rate when possible, with a clear means of specifying the target speed.

Comment: Thanks very much!  In the end, I used essentially this, but replacing `getTicks` by `getClockTime` from `System.Time`, to avoid the effort of downloading extra packages.  (Haskell is a lazy language, right? :-) )

Answer (score 2):

This builds upon C. A. McCann's anwer, which works nicely but is not time-stable in the long run, in particular when the framerate is not an integer fraction of the tick rate.

```
import GHC.Word (Word32)

-- import CAMcCann'sAnswer (Frame, Animation, displayFrame, getTicks, threadDelay)

atTick :: IO () -> Word32 -> IO ()
act `atTick` t = do
    t' <- getTicks
    let delay = max (1000 * (t-t')) 0
    threadDelay $ fromIntegral delay
    act

runFrames :: Integer -> Animation -> IO ()
runFrames fRate frs = do
    t0 <- getTicks
    mapM_ (\(t,f) -> displayFrame f `atTick` t) $ timecode fRate32 t0 frs
  where timecode ν t0 = zip [ t0 + (1000 * i) `div` ν | i <- [0..] ]
        fRate32 = fromIntegral fRate :: Word32
```

Comment: Ah, nice! In most of my actual code I've had parametric animations based on the time differences, and thus didn't worry too much about the exact frame rate, which is why I didn't think to do this sort of thing of the top of my head. Definitely the way to go for discrete frames, though.